# Display errors in browser instead of having to look in the log files

Tags: debugging, coldfusion

My IP address is listed in the debug IP addresses but when I make coldfusion throw an error intentionally all it does is show me a 500 server error in the browser. I have to login to the server and look in the log file to view the errors.

In this case I just made a bad SQL query intentionally.

In the coldfusion-out.log it shows the error. How do I get it to just work normally?

I added my own IP address to the debug info IP address list in the coldfusion administrator

`<cfdump var="#thisvardoesntexist#">`

I want it to show me the actual problem in the browser.

Comment: What web server are you using?  IIS, Apache, built-in?

Comment: Are you developing on the same network your CF server is logging to? What OS are you on? I have always found it helpful to tail the log files I'm interested in to a console, so that I essentially get real-time debugging without a need to refresh anything. But the console commands vary greatly based on the type of console you're using on the OS.

Comment: @ZCT, Have you enabled the `Enable Request Debugging Output` under the 'Debugging & Logging > Debug Output Settings' in administrator?